# Creating a Calendar Event on Specific Dates in Android?

Tags: android, date, datetime, android-calendar

I have a specific requirement to create a Calendar Event that will occur on specific dates. It is not the scenario it will occur Weekly, monthly, yearly but it may come for 13 days, 14 days, 15 days etc. I have on which dates it will occur but was failing to set the recurring dates. below is my code

```
ContentValues calEvent = new ContentValues();
            calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
            calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
            calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, d.getTime());
            calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, d.getTime()
                    + (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
            calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone
                    .getDefault().getID());
            calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
            calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
            calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.RDATE, sdf1.format(d)
                    + "T033000Z");
            // calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.RRULE, value);
            Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(
                    CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, calEvent);

            // The returned Uri contains the content-retriever URI for the
            // newly-inserted event, including its id
            int id = Integer.parseInt(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            // Toast.makeText(ctx, "Created Calendar Event " + id,
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            eventId = eventId + (eventId.equalsIgnoreCase("") ? id : "," + id);
            ContentValues calReminder = new ContentValues();

            calReminder.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, minutes);
            calReminder.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, id);
            // calReminder.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.HAS_ALARM, 1);
            calReminder.put(Reminders.METHOD, Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
            Uri uri1 = contentResolver.insert(
                    CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, calReminder);

            // The returned Uri contains the content-retriever URI for the
            // newly-inserted event, including its id
            int id1 = Integer.parseInt(uri1.getLastPathSegment());
            // Toast.makeText(ctx, "Created Calendar Reminder " + id1,
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            reminderId = reminderId
                    + (reminderId.equalsIgnoreCase("") ? id1 : "," + id1);
```

When I use the RDATE with comma separated values of dates as there is startdate & enddate provided, Event is created to all dates between startdate & enddate.

Comment: Hmmm... I see a bunch of code, a statement of requirements, and "was failing to set the recurring dates" - which is essentially "it doesn't work".  Please rework your question to 1) show exactly how it doesn't work (what it does, what it doesn't do, what you expect for particular values), and 2) actually *ask a question*.  See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent service_intent = new Intent(your application context,
                            your class.class);

                    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(
                            your application context, 0, service_intent, 0);

                    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    // for 30 mint 60*60*1000
                    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            cal.getTimeInMillis(), APP_DAY_FOR_SERVICE
                                    * APP_HOUR_FOR_SERVICE
                                    * APP_MINUT_FOR_SERVICE
                                    * APP_SECOND_FOR_SERVICE * 1000,
                            pintent);
```

in this code after 24 hour an event is called so if you change APP_DAY_FOR_SERVICE to 2 then after 48 hours an event is tiger so if you want to call event after a specific days like you chose date from calender then mins that day with current day and put answer in APP_DAY_FOR_SERVICE thats it

APP_DAY_FOR_SERVICE
APP_HOUR_FOR_SERVICE
APP_MINUT_FOR_SERVICE these all are integer if you have any query then feel free to ask

Comment: But this will not add the event to default Calendar. I would like to have the event to be added to Calendar also. Using Alertmanager is not perfect answer for me.